# Is there a means to save a Simulink file you are currently working in at regular intervals?

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, autosave

I am attempting to write a script in Python that will save a Simulink file every 5 minutes while I am working in it for convenience (I know this is not a reliable way of protecting your files, but I'm doing it for the sake of curiosity). I found the `matlab.engine` API, but it looks like this would require me to open the Simulink file from a Matlab script, which is not what I want. I have yet to find a similar API for Simulink, and I have not used Python in a while so I imagine there is a more obvious approach that I am overlooking. Here is the script I have so far:

```
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("C:\CM_Projects\May_test\src_cm4sl")

last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
last_hour = last_time.hour
last_minute = last_time.minute

while True:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_hour = current_time.hour
    current_minute = current_time.minute
    if (current_minute - last_minute) = 5
        # save Simulink file here
        print("File succesfully saved at " +str(current_hour) + ":" 
        +str(current_minute))
        last_hour = current_hour
        last_minute = current_minute
        exit()
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, but if you already have the model open (as per the "currently working on" part of your question) then you wouldn't need to open the model from a MATLAB script.  You'd just use `save_system` to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the API exposed by MathWorks to interact with Matlab from Python (checkout [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav)).

Using those is possible for you to connect to your running matlab:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.connect_matlab()
```

And once you are connect you can invoke whatever matlab function you want.
For example, *assuming you have a matlab script in your folder* named `saveMyModel.m`:

```
function a = saveMyModel(model_name)
   save_system(model_name);
end
```

You can call it through Python by invoking:

```
eng.saveMyModel('MyModelName')
```